# Pandas: Apply function to set of groups

Tags: python, pandas

**I have the following problem:**

Given a 2D dataframe, first column with values and second giving categories of the points, I would like to compute a k-means dictionary of the means of each category and assign the centroid that the group mean of a particular value is closest to as a new column in the original data frame.

I would like to do this using `groupby`.

More generally, my problem is, that apply (to my knowledge) only can use functions that are defined on the individual groups (like mean()). k-means needs information on all the groups. Is there a nicer way than transforming everything to numpy arrays and working with these?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2

k=4
raw_data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4))
f = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['A','B'])
groups = df.groupby('A')
means = groups.mean().unstack()
centroids, dictionary = kmeans2(means,k)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
print dictionary
```

What I would like to get now, is a new column in df, that gives the value in dictionary for each entry.

Comment: Can you describe what you tried with groupby a bit more? It seems to be pretty straightforward to me - but again, I am not sure which problem you are talking about.

Comment: @srey123 Excuse the delay. So far, I tried: 
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2

k=4
raw_data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4))
f = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['A','B'])
groups = df.groupby('A')
means = groups.mean().unstack()
centroids, dictionary = kmeans2(means,k)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
print dictionary
What I would like to get now, is a new column in df, that gives the value in dictionary for each entry. Unfortunately I do not know how to typeset this as code.

Comment: Can you add this in your question it self? Give 4 spaces before every line to type as code. In comments, you can't post code.

Comment: @srey123 Done, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2

k = 4
raw_data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4))
f = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['A','B'])
groups = df.groupby('A')

means_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(groups.mean())
centroid, means_data_frame['cluster'] = kmeans2(means_data_frame['B'], k)
df.join(means_data_frame, rsuffix='_mean', on='A')
```

This will append 2 more columns to df `B_mean` and `cluster` denoting the group's mean and the cluster that group's mean is closest to, respectively.

If you really want to use `apply`, you can write a function to read the cluster value from `means_data_frame` and assign it to a new column in `df`